# Save multiple dictionaries as separate excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have 3 dictionaries
`true_positive_count , false_positive_count and true_negative_count` contains class names as keys containing integers as values
example -
`count_true_positives = {"A" : 3 , "B" : 4}`
`count_false_negatives = {"A" : 2 , "B" : 0}`
`count_false_positives = {"A" : 9 , "B" : 1}`
I am aggregating these in a single dictionary called confusion_matrix by looping over class names and fetching the counts for respective classes. So for this example the loop will be

```
for class_name in class_names:
    conf_matrix = {}
    conf_matrix["tp"] = count_true_positives[class_name]
    conf_matrix["fp"] = count_false_positives[class_name]
    conf_matrix["fn"] = count_false_negatives[class_name]
```

I would like to save the conf_maxtrix for each class as an excel sheet inside an excel work book with the name of the sheet as the name of the class.
How do I do this ? (Python 3.x)

Comment: Check out https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Use Xlsxwriter:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet for each class.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('my_excel_file.xlsx')

for class_name in class_names:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(class_name)

   # Add the data you want
   row = 0
   col = 0
   worksheet.write(row, col, <here goes your data>)


workbook.close()
```

You can add worksheets with a customized name using the `add_worksheet` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you need xls file you can use this module xlwt else use xlsxwriter like @SimonFink

```
import xlwt # to writing file excel with xls extension

location="my_file.xls"#path + file name if the python code there isn't in the same folder
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()

# example row and column of the cell
row=2
col=2

for class_name in class_names:
    sheet=wb.add_sheet(class_name)
    #other your code
    sheet.write(row,col,#your data)

workbook.save(location)
```